# BackTrack 4 R1 Release VMware Image

Tags: linux

I have download one file called BackTrack 4 R1 Release VMware Image.
Then I run Vmwareplayer. I don't how to log on into its system.

My question is, I never used it before, how can I log into this software or I need to buy license for using it.

Thanks,
Sopolin Ung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/tutorials/backtrack-hard-drive-install/) and [this](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/tutorials/backtrack-vmware-install/). I can't help to wonder what you want to do with it though.